# Youtube API higher quota (form) : response time and price

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, quota

my team uses the Youtube API for a 2 week contest, where participants have to send a video. We want these videos to be hosted on Youtube, only for 3 or 4 weeks.

However, according to the [Youtube's API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota) and the [Quota Calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) :

> A video upload has a cost of approximately 1600 units.

and

> Queries per day (default) : 10 000 units (max)

This means that we can **not have more than 6.25 videos sent per day**, which is very problematic in our case.

It is also indicated:

> If you reach the quota limit, you can request additional quota on the
> Quotas tab in the Developer's Console.
>
> [To increase this maximum value, you can request a higher quota with this form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSd5HxReFtxATJLNfLwQiucfQwYL295Xemgc6nhFXo1vcitg3A/viewform).

We have completed this very long form (yesterday), so we have three questions:

1. How long does YouTube have to respond to this form and what are the delay for increasing the quota?
2. We have a billing account, what is the price of a quota increase over 3 or 4 weeks if it's necessary to pay ?
3. Do you think it is possible to contact live (phone / chat) to speed up our request?

These questions may sound silly, but it's an emergency and I have not found answers to my many searches here and in the API documentation.

Maybe some people here have already asked for a quota increase and will be able to answer those questions.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I'm in the same boat. Did you get a response yet?

Comment: Hey, any response from YouTube team?

Comment: The form was sent on the 15/02, we received a response from Youtube on 25/02 (10 days later). Response : "Your quota extension request has been rejected based on the information you provided because of the following reason:The project number provided is invalid.". So we abandoned the choice of the Youtube API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How long does YouTube have to respond to this form and what are the delay for increasing the quota?

It really depends upon the API.  Some can take as long as two months others take a few weeks. So expect it will take a while.

> We have a billing account, what is the price of a quota increase over 3 or 4 weeks if it's necessary to pay ?

To my knowledge the YouTube API is a free API. To my knowledge there is no public pricing for it.

However if they contact you can work with a developer relations manager to increase your API quota for a price. It isn’t documented because it varies based on an application-by-application basis.

> Do you think it is possible to contact live (phone / chat) to speed up our request?

Since you have requested a quota increase.  Developer relations may contact you and work with you on giving you what you need.

Comment: The second part of your answer is wrong.  You can work with a developer relations manager to increase your API quota for a price.  It isn’t documented because it varies based on an application-by-application basis.

Comment: You also don’t need an account with millions of subscribers to reach YouTube dev relations.  I did this with an app prior to release and discussed increasing my quota.

Comment: Give me a minute i will tweek my anwser.  The apps i have  created were always small i have never been contacted

Comment: @JAL how did you get a developer relations manager? I want to pay to increase the speed in their response to my quota increase form.

Comment: @James I dont think thats how it works.  I think you need to wait.