# YouTube API Quota - Size and Usage

Tags: youtube-api

Does using the YouTube API to check a channel for a new video use up the quota points? Is there a way to do this without using the quota points? Also, can you get more quota points above the default 10,000? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

All requests use up quota points. You can use the quota 
calculator (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) to find out how many quota points will be required.

You can request more quote points from Youtube directly if your business case justifies that, see (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54822960/2692307) for more details.