# Pricing structure after quota exceeds youtube-v3-api

Tags: youtube-data-api

I wanted to know and understand the pricing structure of YouTube Data API v3 after the daily quota of 10,000 units is exceeded.

I understood the [quota calculation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost#comments).

Before requesting for additional quota by filling [this](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form) form, I want to understand the pricing structure of it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no such thing as *pricing structure of YouTube Data API*. This API is free service (albeit its users accept -- have to accept -- a set of conditions stipulated for example by [DTOS](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies)).

Comment: Thanks for reply. There are many articles which says that pricing varies from user's application to application. [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54722138/youtube-api-higher-quota-form-response-time-and-price). can i directly get in contact with Youtube Support team?

Comment: I know of only one API related public Google forum: its [own issue tracker site](http://issuetracker.google.com/). You may well try to repeat your question on that forum too. But, to my knowledge, Google staff [already provided answers](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172776504#comment2) similar to the one I gave you above.